# Filtering a list of react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

I have a code like this (jsx stuff):

```
let my_components = [<TCol dataField = {'id'} ... >{'id'}</TCol>];
    my_components.push(<TCol dataField = {'name'} ... >{'name'}</TCol>);
    ...
    my_components.push(<TCol dataField = {'zip'} ... >{'zip'}</TCol>);
    my_components.push(<TCol dataField = {'age'} ... >{'age'}</TCol>);
```

I also have another list like: hideComps = {'zip', 'age'}. I need to get another object like my_components where each element belongs to my_components but its dataField is not in hideComps. Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you just store a list of the data, and generate the components from there?

Comment: The problem is that besides dataField there are other complex options that could drastically differ between each of them.

Comment: Maybe I should create a map

Answer (score 0):

Technicaly it's quite simple, if don't consider that it's a bad pattern.
And you don't have to write like this `dataField = {'id'}`, it's not necessary. You may write just `dataField="id"`

```js
const hideComps = ['zip', 'age'];

let my_components = [<Main dataField="id">{'id'}</Main>];
my_components.push(<Main dataField="name">{'name'}</Main>);

my_components.push(<Main dataField="zip">{'zip'}</Main>);
my_components.push(<Main dataField="age">{'age'}</Main>);

const filtered_components = my_components.filter(item => hideComps.indexOf(item.props.dataField) === -1);
```

When you are creating a component (doesn't matter via JSX or via React.createElement or anyhow else), you are receiving a link to the `React Component` which is essentially a common JavaScript `Object`(if you don't use `TypeScript` of course) and you are able to access their `props`.